# Servlet threading model and ThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, threadpool

I'm using [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) in a servlet under the assumption that any reference to the ThreadLocal value won't outlive the request.  This assumption is based on the fact that servlets kick off a thread for each request.  One thing I'm unsure of is what happens when the thread goes into a thread pool -- If this happens, can a `ThreadLocal` value set during a previous request be present in a subsequent request if the same thread is used to service it? Or is it considered a "new" thread as far as java is concerned?

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403809/java-cached-thread-pool-and-thread-local

Comment: If you are using a Thread Pool it is not a new thread each time and the ThreadLocal will be retained.  You can clear all ThreadLocals for a thread with a hack, but it is better if you can change your code so you don't need to do this.